# Difference between pose and rest position

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

Pose and Rest position differ.

Updated with blend file below:

I understand that this could be due to the IK constraints I have. What I'm doing is rigging first then I'm going to apply the weight painting after. Is this offset difference going to cause problems. IE weird deformation of the mesh?

And is there a way to make the pose position like the rest even with the IK constraints?

Sorry if this is a noob question. Help is much appreciated.

blender file
[image]

Comment: Yes it will cause problems. It is best if the constraints don't change the bones from rest position on their own. It's hard to tell what is wrong with those constraints. You can upload a .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. That should make things faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was using the human metarig with a model I bought off turbosquid. But I don't think the rig fits well with it. So I'm going to start over with the rig that came with the model.

The model itself is rigged and weighted in lightwave, but when I try to import the lwo file it only imports the rig and the model, but doesn't import the bone weights etc. from what I read about the script, it's suppose to be able to import the weights into blender. Do you know why it is not?